# What does this javascript code snippet do?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml, coffeescript

This is a short question on account that I haven't found the proper answer by using Google. 
Ok, I have this Rails project which has a lot of JavaScript files (CoffeeScript Actually), and it appears that the code that gets the balls rolling is this...

**index.html.haml**

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function () {
    window.Application.init()
  });
```

That's all there is inside, I have no idea what does the line: **window.Application.init()** do? Could you guys please explain it to me?

I'm assuming this is very important since the project is mostly a bunch of coffescript files, and hardly any server-side processing.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: (I found the code for the Application class)

```
class Application
  # Creates the map by using the geolocation center
  # Returns a deferred promise with the bounds
  setup = (position) ->
    deferred = new $.Deferred()
    Ext.setup
      glossOnIcon: false
      onReady: ->
        Application.mapPanel = new MapPanel(position, deferred)
        Application.loading = new Ext.LoadMask( Ext.getBody(), { msg: "Loading..." } )

    deferred.promise()

  # Handles the geolocation error.
  @onFail = ->
    Ext.setup
      onReady: ->
        new Ext.Panel
          fullscreen: true,
          dockedItems: [],
          items: []

        Ext.Msg.confirm "Position Unavailable",
          "Can not confirm your location. Would you like to go to the instructions page?",
          (button) ->
            document.location = if button == "no" then "/posts" else "/instructions"

  @init = ->
    Geolocation.onStart = (position) ->
      $.when(setup(position)).pipe(Post.latest).then (data) ->
        Application.mapPanel.paintPosts data

    Geolocation.onUserRejected = @onFail
    Geolocation.init()

window.Application = Application
```

Comment: Without seeing the code for the "Application" object, it's impossible to say for sure. It could literally be anything.

Comment: I've posted the requested code there. I'd like to know in general terms what does the Syntax: window.Anything = Anything do? (I obviously undestand 'Anything' is a Coffeescript class), but I want to know what does that syntax finally accomplish. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erm... it runs the function `window.Application.init` which was probably attached to the `window` in some other coffeescript file. Look for a file containing `class window.Application` or `window.Application =`.

Comment: You're right, Application is a fully-fledged Coffeescript class. Fortunately, this can now lead to my other question.. Could you please explain to me, What does the Syntax: window.Application = Application do? (I've posted some code in the original Question), I see a lot of times this being used, like window.Klass = Klass, or window.OtherClass = OtherClass. What does that do? Thank you..

Comment: @user766388: This makes stuff visible outside of the file.

Comment: Coffee Script hides all functions, class and variables in a file based private scope.  The way to get something out of that scope is to set a property of the global object (`window` in a browser), which makes it available everywhere.  `Application` needs to be accessible everywhere, so `window.Application = Application` sets the local value of `Application` to the `Application` property of the global object, thereby making it available everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your follow-on question:

```
window.Application = Application
```

effectively promotes the local reference "Application" to a global symbol.  The `window` object in the browser is the global scope, and global variables are references therefore to properties of `window`.  Therefore, creating a property of `window` and setting it to some value (an object, maybe a function in this case; I don't know much about Coffeescript) makes that value available globally.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a Coffeescript learner also, so I was very confused about this topic. I'll have to research further, thank you very much once more.

Answer (score 0):

It starts the application which is built with coffeescript. Look at the initializer of the application and debug it step by step.